# MySQL JOIN returns unexpected values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm trying to do a simple mysql request and I'm having problems.

I have 2 tables defined like below:

```
currencies
______________________________________________________________________________________
currency_id | currency_name | currency_symbol | currency_active | currency_auto_update

exchange_rates
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
exchange_rate_id | currency_id | exchange_rate_date | exchange_rate_value | exchange_rate_added_date
```

What I want to do is to select the last row inside `exchange_rates` for the active currency.

I did it like this:

```
SELECT c.currency_id, c.currency_name, c.currency_symbol, c.currency_active, er.exchange_rate_id, er.exchange_rate_date, er.exchange_rate_value
FROM currencies c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT er1.exchange_rate_id, er1.currency_id, er1.exchange_rate_date, er1.exchange_rate_value
    FROM exchange_rates er1
    ORDER BY er1.exchange_rate_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
    ) AS er
ON er.currency_id=c.currency_id
WHERE c.currency_active='1'
```

This is returning me `NULL` values from the `exchange_rates` table, even if there are matching rows

I've tried to remove `LIMIT 1` but if I do it like this is returning me all the rows for active currency, which is not the solution I want

How should this query look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.currency_id, c.currency_name, c.currency_symbol, c.currency_active, er.exchange_rate_id, er.exchange_rate_date, er.exchange_rate_value
FROM currencies c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT er1.exchange_rate_id, er1.currency_id, er1.exchange_rate_date, er1.exchange_rate_value
    FROM exchange_rates er1
    ORDER BY er1.exchange_rate_date DESC) AS A GROUP BY currency_id 
    ) AS er
ON er.currency_id=c.currency_id
WHERE c.currency_active='1'
```

Comment: This is working fine.. Thanks for your answer.. there are too many selects I think, but is working as I aspected

Comment: I see this working fine... nice!! i didn't know that a GROUP BY query would have returned the first record... +1

Answer (score 0):

The idea of query look correct to me. your left join query should return the row with the newest exchange rate. you could use inner join here because there must be a currency refering to this...

```
SELECT c.currency_id, c.currency_name, c.currency_symbol, c.currency_active, er.exchange_rate_id, er.exchange_rate_date, er.exchange_rate_value
FROM currencies c
INNER JOIN exchange_rates_er1 e ON e.currency_id = c.currency_id
WHERE c.currency_active='1'
ORDER BY e.exchange_rate_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it only returns data for one currency. I think the OP wants to return one row per currency.

Comment: i see... you already gave the hint for group concat so nothing left to do here :)